# Get coverage from class in other module tested with QuarkusUnitTest

Tags: gradle, code-coverage, jacoco, quarkus-extension

In the jacoco coverage of my quarkus extension, I am missing certain classes. The project contains to submodules, which finally causing the issue.

Example project: https://github.com/HerrDerb/quarkus-extension-coverage-issue

As I cannot run `QuarkusTest` in a quarkus extension runtime module, I test certain runtime classes with a `QuarkusUnitTest` in my deployment module. These beans under test are missing in the final coverage report of the deployment module

I am testing the class `MyBean` inside of the deployment module. When running `./gradlew test jacocoTestReport` it will generate the folder `deplyoment/build/reports/jacacoco`. Looking over the html reports files, it is visible that the coverage report of `MyBean` is missing. This is, because the bean is actually not implemented inside of the deployment module. Moving it test-wise from the runtime module to the deployment module will result in the desired coverage.

I tried to play around with jacoco properties inside the debployment/build.gradle which did not result in any success:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    additionalSourceDirs.from project(':runtime').sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}
```

How can I include "external" beans (from another module) in the coverage report of my `QuarkusUnitTest`?